# Python Pandas drop columns running out of resources - killed

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete columns from a large dataset using Pandas like this...

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", )
data.drop(data.columns[[0, 1, 2]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The reading of the dataset is working correctly, but when the drop happens it gives a 'killed' error which I am assuming is due to a lack of resources.

Is there an alternative more efficient way of dropping the columns?

Comment: just read the needed columns using usecols

Answer (score 2):

You can just avoid loading them in the first place when you [read the CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). This can be done with the `usecols` argument in `pd.read_csv`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", usecols=[3, 4, 5])
```

> **usecols:** list-like or callable, optional
>   Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].

Comment: That still gives me the killed message

Answer (score 1):

Apart from just reading the columns you needed with the help of usecols, you can also set low_memory=False such that your process will not get killed.

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", usecols=[1,2,3], low_memory=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the column parameter, just type the columns name. You **don't have to specify** `axis=1` part.

```
data.drop(columns=['col_name_1','col_name_2'], inplace=True)
```